# The result of docker exec command

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I need to know in my shell script the output of some docker exec commands, for example I have an nginx container and in my script I run:

`docker exec -it containerName /etc/init.d/nginx configtest`

I want to continue script execution only if nginx config test is success, not when fail.

I've tried out to use `$?`, but it is `0` even then configtest output is fail (because docker exec is successfully executed, as I understand).

Comment: `docker exec -it mynginx /etc/init.d/nginx configtest` returns `1` for me if there is any error in config file

Comment: @anubhava can you write down the example script? I've tried out this: `docker exec -it containerName /etc/init.d/nginx configtest ... echo $? ... exit` and got the following: `...Test fail ... 0` (notice 0 not expected 1)

Answer (score 21):

I found [this](https://github.com/docksal/docksal/commit/34d1bb094e8f7c8265672f8b46bfa4035fee574f) to be working quite well:

```
docker exec -t -i my-container sh -c 'my-command; exit $?'
```

Answer (score 13):

Translating my comment into an answer. This should work:

```
docker exec -it mynginx /etc/init.d/nginx configtest && echo "pass" || echo "fail"
```

It works for me.

Comment: I really like it. Simple and elegant!

Answer (score 5):

The [`api/client/exec.go#L97-L100`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/375f754f49ee6e9de942816a47a21a715fe3bacb/api/client/exec.go#L97-L100) does get the exit code:

```
var status int
if _, status, err = getExecExitCode(cli, execID); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

That comes from [`api/client/utils.go#L84-L97`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/75d69ce0da2e360773736502acd92d4a9cf7faa5/api/client/utils.go#L84-L97)

```
// getExecExitCode perform an inspect on the exec command. It returns
// the running state and the exit code.
func getExecExitCode(cli *DockerCli, execID string) (bool, int, error) {
    resp, err := cli.client.ContainerExecInspect(execID)
    if err != nil {
        // If we can't connect, then the daemon probably died.
        if err != lib.ErrConnectionFailed {
            return false, -1, err
        }
        return false, -1, nil
    }

    return resp.Running, resp.ExitCode, nil
}
```

So if your command fail, you will get the exit code.
Although, [as mentioned here, you could use `nginx -t` instead of `configtest`](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/763).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to immediately respond to exit code returned from a process triggered by `docker exec` command, you could do something like this.

```sh
docker exec my-app-container /app/scripts/test.sh
UNIT_TEST_EXIT_CODE=$? # Get exit code from last command (/app/scripts/test.sh)
... # do some stuff after unit testing 
exit $UNIT_TEST_EXIT_CODE
```

I used this approach in the context of CI/CD pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

A new version ready to test to run a bash command:

```
docker exec -t -i oracle bash -c "echo hola && exit"
hola
```